# How should I get rid of FNU in my F1- visa at this point, while I already spent an year of my studies with same visa?

Tags: usa, passports, study

I have FNU written in my F1- Visa and it is causing lots of troubles for me. It took more than 2 months to get my SSN and driver's license. To eliminate future complexities I need guidance about the process to get rid of FNU thing.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change an existing visa. You need to get a new passport issued with your names listed "correctly" in the machine readable field and apply for a new visa.

Comment: Do you have more than one name?

Comment: Is your first name "Fnu" and it gets mistaken for first-name-unknown, or is your first name *actually* FNU? Sorry, this is confusing with the Stack Exchange username you chose… ;)

Comment: The visa is issued in the name that appears in the passport. Is the name in your passport your legal name? What future complexities do you anticipate? Now that you have your SSN and driver’s licence, legally changing your name might in itself provoke other complexities.

Comment: If you are studying at a major university, there may be someone in the international students office that can help. Also, if there is a law school associated with the university, someone there might be able to help.

Comment: @Traveller many jurisdictions, including many US states (if not most) do not actually have a concept of a "legal name" that is the single such name that may be used to refer to someone in formal legal contexts.  Changing the name used on various identification documents is not necessarily tantamount to "legally changing your name."

Comment: @lambshaanxy what if the visa gets rejected? And, Should I need to go back to my country  to further this process?

Comment: @phoog I have one given name that is Ambreen n I don't have any last name on my birth certificate due to my parents separation.

Comment: @FnuAmbreen If you don't have two names, your US visa will always be issued as "FNU". The only way to fix this is to legally change your name.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest time to get rid of "FNU" is before your first entry to the US. However, some students find themselves in your situation where they've already reached the US and want to get rid of FNU. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Get a new passport which shows separately your family name(s) versus given name(s). In the machine readable zone, a double-separator ">>" should separate your family name(s) from your given name(s). Depending on your country, you may be able to get the new passport in the US or you may have to get it at home.
2. Provide your new passport to your university international student office advisor/staff (DSO) and get an updated I-20 showing the new name(s). Your SEVIS ID (number starting with N) should not change if you are not interrupting your studies.
3. Outside of the US, apply for a new F-1 visa with your new name, passport and I-20. You must inform them about your previous name and previous visa.
4. Enter the US with your new visa, passport and I-20. Be prepared to explain the change if they ask.
5. Download and print your new I-94 and travel history under both names and passports. If there is any problem, you may need to get it corrected by going to CBP at the airport.
6. Now that your passport, I-20, visa, and I-94 all have the new name without FNU, you're ready to apply for a new social security card and driver's license. For each of these, if you already had one with FNU, you must inform them about it when you apply. Then they should update your name without changing the number.

Comment: This answer assumes that the asker _has_ separable family name(s) and given name(s), which may not be the case.